# How to call 2 model function in one function controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, so please help me to solve my problem.

I want to call my two model function in  one function controller. Heres  my two model function:

```
public function getposts($postid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_endangered');
    $this->db->where(['endangeredid'=>$postid]);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function getSinglePost($postid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_images');
    //$this->db->join('tbl_images');
    $this->db->where(['endangeredid'=>$postid]);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

And here is my function controller:

```
public function viewAnimals($postid){
    if(!$this->session->userdata("id") )
        return redirect("AuthCon/login");

    $this->load->model('Show');
    $posts = $this->Show->getSinglePost($postid);
    //$posts = $this->Show->getposts($postid);
    $this->load->view('Showimage',['posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

In that code above I always get the first one that I declared. I want to fetch the getposts and getSinglePost inside the function viewAnimals controller.

Hopeyou can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this in the controller

```
public function viewAnimals($postid){

  if(!$this->session->userdata("id"))
      return redirect("AuthCon/login");

  $this->load->model('Show');
  $data['images'] = $this->Show->getSinglePost($postid);
  $data['endangered'] = $this->Show->getposts($postid);
  $this->load->view('Showimage', $data);
}
```

Another way is to use `join()` and only one model function

```
public function getSinglePost($postid){

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('tbl_images');
  $this->db->join('tbl_endangered', 'tbl_endangered.endangeredid = tbl_images.endangeredid');
  $this->db->where('tbl_images.endangeredid', $postid);
  return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using same variable name is creating a mess. 
you can try assigning to `posts` array with output in it.

```
$this->load->model('Show');
$posts['getSinglePostData'] = $this->Show->getSinglePost($postid);
$posts['getPostsData'] = $this->Show->getposts($postid);
$this->load->view('Showimage',$posts);
```